# Bootstrapping issues with zend_test/phpunit

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-test

I am working with Zend_Test. Below is my tests/bootstrap.php file:

```
// Define path to application directory
defined('APPLICATION_PATH')
    || define('APPLICATION_PATH', realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../application'));

// Define application environment
defined('APPLICATION_ENV')
    || define('APPLICATION_ENV', 'testing');

// Ensure library/ is on include_path
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
    realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library'),
    get_include_path(),
)));

require_once 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
$autoloader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
$autoloader->registerNamespace('Ca_');

Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::addPrefix('Ca_Controller_Action_Helper');

$resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(array(
        'namespace' => "Social",
        'basePath'  => APPLICATION_PATH . "/../library",
));
$resourceLoader->addResourceType('facebook', 'Facebook/', 'Facebook');
```

This is my setUp() method in my test class (which is extending Zend_Test_PHPUnit_DatabaseTestCase):

```
public function setUp()
{
    $this->bootstrap = new Zend_Application(APPLICATION_ENV, APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini');
    $this->entityUser = new Ca_Model_Entity_User_Registered();
    $a = $this->getAdapter();
    $a->setFetchMode(Zend_Db::FETCH_OBJ);
$a->query("SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;");     
parent::setUp();        
}
```

Now, when running a unit test I get the following error for this particular line of code:

```
$bootstrap = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getParam('bootstrap');
$options = $bootstrap->getOptions();
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getOptions() on a non-object

Does anyone know what is causing the issue and how I can resolve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677462/zend-test-on-action-helper-accessing-bootstrap-getoptions-error

Comment: that was fixed in 1.10. I am using 1.11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. Ended up loading the application config in bootstrap and storing it in Zend_Registry. Much easier that way.

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
Zend_Registry::set('config', $config);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is treating a single parameter as an object.

From the docs at: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.front.html

```
getParam($name) allows you to retrieve a single parameter 
at a time, using $name as the identifier.
```

Comment: That doesnt explain why it works via a webserver but not in uTesting